# throw exception when get value from SQL SERVER (DATE) in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a problem with query in C#

```
SqlCommand kwerenda = new SqlCommand("
SELECT [OsobaZglaszajaca],
       [OsobaDokonujacaNaprawy],
       [OsobaZglaszajacaUwage],
       CONVERT(VARCHAR, [DataZgloszenia]),
       CONVERT(VARCHAR, [PrzewidywanyTerminNaprawy]),
       CONVERT(VARCHAR, [DataNaprawy]),
       [TypUsterki],
       [Maszyna],
       [RodzajUsterki],
       [UwagiUE],
       [UwagiProdukcja]
FROM   warning
WHERE  DataZgloszenia = 'dateadd(day,datediff(day,14,GETDATE()),0)'
ORDER  BY CzyWazne ASC 
", Form1.connect);
```

Where are words "Data" is Date in SQL and throw

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: What is the datatype of `DataZgloszenia` column ?

Comment: Remove the single quotes from the `dateadd` line - `WHERE  DataZgloszenia = dateadd(day,datediff(day,14,GETDATE()),0)`.

Comment: data type is date

Comment: Thank you i look for this 1 week :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the single quotes in where condition

```
SELECT [OsobaZglaszajaca],
       ...
FROM   warning
WHERE  DataZgloszenia = dateadd(day,datediff(day,14,GETDATE()),0) --here
ORDER  BY CzyWazne ASC
```

*Single quotes* are used for `string literals` and for `dates` that are hard coded

Also it is worth noting that, `14` in here `dateadd(day,datediff(day,14,GETDATE()),0)` will be interpreted as `1900-01-15 00:00:00.000`.

It can be written as `cast(dateadd(day,-14,GETDATE()) as date)`

Comment: Thank you i look for this 1 week :)